# Did Xcode 4.1 support ARC?

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I wrote project by ARC in Xcode 4.2, but 4.2 cannot submit apps to the app store and miss armv6 architecture. Now I need to downgrade Xcode. But if I do this, I'll have a lot work to do. Did Xcode 4.1 support ARC? Thanks for help!!!

Comment: You could just upgrade to 4.5. 4.5 can't even build for ARMv6 so you're definitely not going to be expected to build for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  4.1 does not have ARC.  Sorry.